# How to get sorted data from mat-table of all pages?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm looking for a method to extract sorted data and save it under `sortedData` from `dataSource` of mat-table in order to save it to CSV file. There are filters and pagination applied to dataSource through

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate; this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
```

and I couldn't find any working solution except this

```
this.dataSource.connect().subscribe((data) => (this.sortedData = data))
```

but this solution returns data limited only to single page when applying MatPaginator and this

```
this.sortedData = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.data, this.dataSource.sort)
```

which returns all data ignoring filtration.

Any ideas how could I get all sorted and filtered data (data of all pages) from dataSource?

Comment: Maybe be use filteredData instead of data => const sortedData = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData, this.dataSource.sort);

Comment: That works! many thanks :). If you added it as the answer I and others could rate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filteredData :

> The filtered set of data that has been matched by the filter string,
> or all the data if there is no filter.

```
const sortedData = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData, this.dataSource.sort)
```

Comment: That works!! In order to avoid Type Error it has to be checked on existence of dataSource.sort by ```if (this.dataSource.sort) {
      this.sortedData = this.dataSource.sortData(
        this.dataSource.filteredData,
        this.dataSource.sort
      );
    }```